# QtUdpSocket still listening on port after closing MainWindow

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside

I have a `QWidget` (`udpWidget`) instantiated in a `QMainWindow` (`udpMainWindow`). I am creating `udpMainWindow` from another `QMainWindow`

There is some `ValueError` exception occurring (which I am going to fix).
When I close the window of `udpMainWindow`, I can no longer do a bind to the port until I close the entire program. I understand I need to fix the exception that is occurring, however I don't understand why after closing the udpMainWindow that the resource (0.0.0.0:12345) is still listening.

```
class udpWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(udpWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.listenSocket=QtNetwork.QtUdpSocket()
        ...

    def do_something(self)       
        self.listenSocket.bind(12345)
        ...
        #Some Exception Occurs

        self.listenSocket.close()

    def destroy(self, destroyWindow, destroySubWindows):
        self.listenSocket.close()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.listenSocket.close()
        event.accept()

class udpMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(udpMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        myUdpWidget=udpWidget(self)
        myButton.clicked.connect(myUdpWidget.do_something)
```

**Edit 1**:

Here is a fully functional example. When you start listening on the "UDP Main Window" using the PushButton, then close using the 'X' button, the port doesn't free up. Then when you attempt to listen with the "Main Main Window" it fails to bind because it is still in use.

Steps to reproduce problem:

1. Run Program
2. Click "Listen to port 12345" on "UDP Main Window"
3. *Click "Listen to port 12345" on "Main Main Window" *(this just confirms that the port is busy, not necessary to reproduce problem.
4. Click 'x' to close "UDP Main Window"
5. Click "Listen to port 12345" on "Main Main Window" This will now fail to connect.

The Code

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtNetwork

class udpWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(udpWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.listenSocket=QtNetwork.QUdpSocket()
        #bindResult=self.listenSocket.bind(12345)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def start_listening(self):
        bindResult=self.listenSocket.bind(12345)
        print "binding: {}".format(bindResult)
        raise ValueError("invalid Number") #Simulate exception occuring.
        self.listenSocket.close()


    def destroy(self, destroyWindow, destroySubWindows):
        print "udpWidget.destroy called"
        self.listenSocket.close()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print "udpWidget.closeEvent called"
        self.listenSocket.close()
        event.accept()

class udpMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(udpMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("UDP Main Window")
        self.myUdpWidget=udpWidget(self)
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Listen to port 12345")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.myUdpWidget.start_listening)
        self.setCentralWidget(btn)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print "udpMainWindow.closeEvent called"
        #self.myUdpWidget.listenSocket.close()


class mainMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(mainMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Main Window")
        myUdpMainWindow = udpMainWindow(self)
        myUdpMainWindow.show()
        self.listenSocket=QtNetwork.QUdpSocket()
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Listen to port 12345")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.connect_udp)
        self.setCentralWidget(btn)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def connect_udp(self):
        bindResult=self.listenSocket.bind(12345)
        print "binding: {}".format(bindResult)



if __name__=="__main__":
   myApp = QtGui.QApplication([])
   myMainMainWindow = mainMainWindow(None)
   myMainMainWindow.show()
   myApp.exec_()
```

Comment: Based on what you've provided, I don't see anything that would call self.listenSocket.close() when updMainWindow is closed. With the exception, we never get there when do_something() runs. Although destroy() and closeEvent() both close the socket, I'm not convinced that either of those will be called on updMainWindow.close(). It may be that all you need to do is resolve the exception that prevents do_something from calling close on the socket.

Comment: Also, it's not clear whether by "closing the udpMainWindow" you mean calling a close method on the updMainWindow object or clicking the X close in the corner of the window on your display so that the visible window closes. When you listen on a socket, it's actually the OS that does the listening for you. It will continue listening until you tell it to stop, by calling close on the socket or terminating your process...

Comment: @TomBarron Yes, by fixing the `Exception` the close does get called. I was more concerned about why the UDP object seems to still hold onto the port even after the Window is closed. It is more of that it isn't behaving how I had anticipated.

Comment: I hear you. I don't know for sure, but I imagine it's the OS that was keeping the resource active because with the exception getting in the way, it wasn't getting any indication that you were done with it until your process terminated and it did post-process cleanup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal that if you don't close the socket then it will not be closed until you exit from the application. Closing a window is not enough, the socket belongs to the application and not to the window (the two windows are in the same process).
If you want to close the socket, you must decide where to do it.

If you want to close the socket at the end of the start_listening function, then simply use exception handling where exception can happen:

```
    try:
        # here is the part where exception can happen
        raise ValueError("invalid Number") #Simulate exception occuring.
    except ValueError:
        # handle error here

    self.listenSocket.close()
```

If you want to close it in the closeEvent of the udpMainwindow, then simply uncomment the line

```
    self.myUdpWidget.listenSocket.close()
```

In this code for both windows the closeEvent is called when closing:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtNetwork

class udpMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(udpMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("UDP Main Window")
        self.listenSocket=QtNetwork.QUdpSocket()
        #self.myUdpWidget=udpWidget(self)
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Listen to port 12345")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.start_listening)
        self.setCentralWidget(btn)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print "udpMainWindow.closeEvent called"
        #self.listenSocket.close()

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def start_listening(self):
        bindResult=self.listenSocket.bind(12345)
        print "binding: {}".format(bindResult)
        try:
            raise ValueError("invalid Number") #Simulate exception occuring.
        except ValueError:
            # handle error here
            pass
        finally:
            self.listenSocket.close()

class mainMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(mainMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Main Window")
        myUdpMainWindow = udpMainWindow(self)
        myUdpMainWindow.show()
        self.listenSocket=QtNetwork.QUdpSocket()
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Listen to port 12345")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.connect_udp)
        self.setCentralWidget(btn)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def connect_udp(self):
        bindResult=self.listenSocket.bind(12345)
        print "binding: {}".format(bindResult)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print "mainMainWindow.closeEvent called"
        #self.listenSocket.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
   myApp = QtGui.QApplication([])
   myMainMainWindow = mainMainWindow(None)
   myMainMainWindow.show()
   myApp.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, however they really don't answer what I was looking for, because I realize already that I can `try: except: finally:` the issue. (btw you would want to put the `self.listenSocket.close()` in a `finally:` clause to ensure that it gets executed if say some other issue arose, or if the exception handler raises, etc. And yes, I do realize that uncommenting that line will fix the issue as well, that is a line I put in the code to work around it.

Comment: Yes, you can put it into finally clause. Your decision. However you can also write try in try. It depends. Maybe the close statement is not following the part where your exception happens. That's why I wrote it so. Beside that I also gave you explanation, why it behaves so. What else do you need?

Comment: I guess my follow up is that I am not sure why the `closeEvent` nor the `destroy` event got called when the Window closes? It also doesn't make sense to me that a `QtNetwork.QUdpSocket` object created in the Window would belong to the application. To me it doesn't make sense that the widget's parent needs to know about the UdpSocket at all. Your explanation of why is good, but the solution you provide is already in the question.

Comment: The closeEvent is called where it is defined, i.e. if you close the udpMainWindow. For the mainMainWindow there is no closeEvent defined. The udpWidget is useless, I think, so I have edited my answer to include a cleaner version of your code. The socket will still live after closing the window if you don't close it explicitly. By the way the udpMainWindow instance itself will live after closing it. It seems that closing it does not free it.

Comment: Thank you. I kept the Widget because it is a MCVE. I was surprised it didn't get cleaned up I had wrongly assumed that closing it destroyed it. Thanks for your help.